# Passing Not serialized Object between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have Activity A with session to server side using this streams:

```
socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 7777);
outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

I'm starting Activity B in which i'm generating GeoPoint (Not Serialized).
now i want to send the The GeoPoint to the server.
How can i do it?

I tried:
1. Using Intent to return the GeoPoint to Activity A. but it works just when activity B is finished and i don't want to close Activiy B yet.
2. sending the outStream,inStream from Activity A to B but they are not serialized.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use application class to passing data. You can keep reference to your socket connection over there.

Answer (score 3):

In such cases, you may want to use a global variable, by overriding the `Application` itself.

For example:

```
public class MyOverridenApp extends Application {

    private static ObjectOutputStream outStream = null;
    private static ObjectInputStream inStream = null;

    public static void setOutStream(ObjectOutputStream outStream) {
        MyOverridenApp.outStream = outStream;
    }

    public static ObjectOutputStream getOutStream() {
        return MyOverridenApp.outStream;
    }
}
```

And use appropriate calls in the activities to set/get the outstream.

Just remember to set this as your application in the manifest:

```
<application androidName=".MyOverridenApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```